# Gmail Nested labels on android

Tags: applications, inbox-by-gmail

I use nested labels on my laptop for organizing  email since it reduces the number of labels I see.
But on my android phone the nesting doesn't  appear to work.
Example
"HOA" as main label and "HOA/docs" as the sublabel. The label is the same of both laptop and phone, but they do not nest on my phone.
Am I missing some setting on my phone or is it just something  that a phone cannot.

Comment: I use gmail by an imap client (openmail). There it works well, the problem is only the assignment of the imap folders to the gmail labels.